# accepts_nested_attributes_for with two relationships to same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-attributes

Guests purchase Items from other guests, so an Item will have a buyer and a seller, and a Guest will have Items purchased and Items bought.

```
class Guest < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :bought_items, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: 'buyer_id'
  has_many :sold_items, class_name: 'Item', foreign_key: 'seller_id'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bought_items, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:price].blank? } , :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sold_items, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:price].blank? } , :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'Guest', foreign_key: 'seller_id', inverse_of: :bought_items
  belongs_to :buyer,  class_name: 'Guest', foreign_key: 'buyer_id', inverse_of: :sold_items

  attr_accessor :buyer_id, :seller_id

end
```

It appears the form is sending the POST data back correctly (I've only coded the purchases so far), for:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9gR+GZfhT4CffM3ML9LkZaYK+eA85a1oLRG+NRqoRnY=",
 "guest"=>{
     "guest_number"=>"3",
     "bought_items_attributes"=>{
        "0"=>{
            "item_number"=>"432",
            "description"=>"test",
            "seller_id"=>"27",
            "sales_price"=>"10.0", "id"=>"1"},
        "1"=>{
            "item_number"=>"",
            "description"=>"",
            "seller_id"=>"27",
            "sales_price"=>"0.0"}
       }
  },
 "commit"=>"Save Changes",
 "id"=>"28"}
```

Updates happen for changing the guest_number, but not for any of the nested attributes. Is there something wrong in the model setup?

This is Rails 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `reject_if` block says to reject data if the `price` attribute is blank, which it is - your post data has `sales_price` instead.

You do also want to get rid of that `attr_accessor` as lucapette points out.

Comment: Oh my. That is indeed the problem. I have been looking at it for *hours*! Sigh...  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The attr_accessor is a problem for sure. Maybe you would have used [attr_accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried and with and without the attr_accessor and the problem still occurs.